# how can I avoid searching among 5 to the power of 300 combinations?

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I'm doing an optimization problem in C language (I'm not a so good at the language). I found a task on the internet.

> A company wants to organize an event and there are 7 competitions in this event. Different families wants to attend these competitions but each family must and can only attend one of the 7 competitions. Each family will give us their 5 choices.
>
> We have a CSV file with the following columns:
>
> family_members, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, choice5.
>
> Each competition can host at least 125 member and at most 250 member.
> For each family we have to calculate a cost of assignment:
>
> cost = 0 euros (if the family was assigned to it’s choice1).
> cost = 50 (if the family was assigned to it’s choice2)
> cost = 50 + 9 * family_members (if the family was assigned to it’s  choice3)
> cost = 100 + 9 * family_members(if the family was assigned to its choice4)
> cost = 200 + 9 * family_members (if the family was assigned to it’s choice5)
>
> and we have a total cost
> total_cost = sum of cost(f) (for f = 1 to number_of_families)
>
> we want to find the best combination of families choices that will give us the minimal total_cost

so if we have 300 families and each family has 5 choices: we will have 5<sup>300</sup> combination of choices. It's impossible to through all these combinations and find the best one.

Is there any other way I can find the best solution without going through all of these?

I've thought about generating 1M or 1B random combination of families choices and take the combination with the minimum total_cost but I wanted to see if there is any other way to it?

Comment: Try greedy approach. That is, assign the families with the most members to the 1'st choice. Once there is no more room to assign, proceed with rest of the families and the second choice. Can't prove it will give an optimal solution (or solution at all) but worth trying...

Comment: Can you share the link to "the task on the internet"?

Comment: (You're close to (re-)discovering one group of heuristics.)

Comment: Reduce the search space. There are 21 ways to select 5 things from 7, so the 300 families have many dpulicate choices.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think it helps. The choices are *given*.

Comment: @WeatherVane I went down that path, but don't forget that order is important. There are 2520 permutations of 5 from 7.

Comment: @WeatherVane OK... so you are saying partition each set into 5 groups. But no, as pmacfarlane says, the order of the choices matters.

Comment: Yes I overlooked that the order of the choices matters. But something else OP can do it to abandon any grouping once it becomes impossible to improve on the current best choice so far.

Comment: "_Each competition can host at least 125 member_" Does this mean a minimum that must be met for the event to proceed?

Comment: @Fe2O3 so presumably each family member counts as a participant, because at least 875 participants are needed?

Comment: @WeatherVane no each participant is a family member, and a family can have many members

Comment: @Fe2O3 I guess there needs to be a minimum number, otherwise there is a completely trivial solution I just though of. I was going to post it as an answer, but it doesn't work if there is a minimum.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that's one of the approaches i did. i sorted descendingly the families based on how many members they have. i think its not the optimal solution

Comment: @tstanisl it's a paper that i found in french if you want i can send it to you

Comment: @pmacfarlane Yeah, it _feels like_ the solution should be more complicated than just "counting noses"... `:-)`

Comment: @WeatherVane i dont understnad why there is 21 way to select 5 from 7. a family dont have a duplicated choice.  but families between them i dont know if there are similar choices.

Comment: @Fe2O3 yes at least a competition must be filled with 125

Comment: Someone should write some code for this, and someone should make a CSV file. Then we can fight it out with implementations of the allocation function. Doesn't seem on-topic here though. I've seen other SE sites with similar things, can't remember which one.

Comment: What class is this from? If it is a combinatorics class, most of the assignments are going to be to find the optimal solution, so we should be looking for ways to carve up the search space to eliminate large portions, so that an complete determination is possible. If it is some sort of class involving heuristics, we are looking for approximation algorithms.

Comment: Re “if we have 300 families”: Why “if”? Is 300 a number you plucked out of the air, or did the assignment explicitly indicate this is a possibility?

Comment: Thinking beyond the obvious, there may be 'n' "Best" solutions, all at the same "cost"... Interesting challenge... `:-)`

Comment: @pmacfarlane i have the csv files if you want them

Comment: @EricPostpischil  It's an algorithms and complexity class.i just said 300 as a number because there like 5 csv files to test the code and the number of families changes from a file to another.

Comment: i thought i can generate random assignments and the calculate the inital cost then starts swapping families choices and at each swap i calculate once again the cost till i find the best combination .

Comment: also using dynamic programming, i can look into the possible combinations and using the constraints and isValid function that returns if i can add that family to that certain competition or not. and this can make get rid of the rest combination that dont satisfy the constraints. It's just an idea i have to write it down and see if i can code something from it

Comment: @SofianeAMIROUCHE: What is the greatest number of families in any of the files? What is the greatest number of members of any family?

Comment: Although it is "brute force", you might try writing a recursive function with backtracking that searches the entire possibility space, reporting when it has success and the associated cost... With a smaller data set, this might expose some optimisation ideas you could try. At least you will then know if there is 1 solution or none... Change 7 events to 4; change 300 families to 50; Change 5 choices to 3... Scale it down to explore the problem in a reasonable timeframe.

Comment: @EricPostpischil there at most 455 families and each family has from 2 to 8 (max) members

Comment: @Fe2O3 i've done it with bracktracking with a small number of families 10 and only 3 competitions. but the problem is when i have 455 families and 7 competitions. its impossible to be done. just generating those combinations will take lifetime hhhh

Comment: We could start by tentatively assigning all families to their first choice and seeing how much that oversubscribes events. Then the task is to move families from oversubscribed events to other events. That should be a smaller problem than considering all potential assignments from scratch.

Comment: Further, any family in an oversubscribed event whose second choice is an undersubscribed event may be moved to their second choice—observe that in a situation where two families cannot both have their first choice but one can have their first while the other has their second, the total cost is the same regardless of which family gets their first choice; it is 50+0 or 0+50. There are some interactions with other assignments, as the number of family members involved affects how many other families can have the choices involved, but this still may help reduce the problem space.

Comment: "generating those combinations"... Hmm... I wonder... If there are multiple families (same number of members) wanting choiceX, there's no reason that the search needs to try each of them at one level of the search... The result would be the same... ie: There are ways to "prune" the effort required... (I'm presuming that the list is/can be sorted from largest to smallest families...) Beware of "local minima"... How will you know any solution is the "minimum cost" achievable?

Comment: MIP solvers are really, really good at this kind of thing. You might not learn a whole lot about optimization by calling out to a library, though.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I will this approach and tell you about the results. And at the end I think I may share my code here.

Comment: @Fe2O3 families may have the same firstchois x but not all the choices are the same so I don't think I I can ignore them. Yes I implemented a sort algorithm that can sort families based on the number of members.

Comment: @EricPostpischil i tried to assign them all to their first choice and i get the following values: 269 270 305 239 220 315 317 for each competition, now i'll try your approach and i will send the result here after.

Comment: the problem is that there is an other assignement in an other question where there'll be another optimization :  Since there is 7 competitions from 0 to 6 
• If competition < 6, Com_cost(competition) = ( ( ( pop ( competition ) − 125) / 400) ∗ pop( jour ) ) ^ ( | pop(competition) − pop(competition+1) | /50)


• If competition = 6, Com_cost(competition) = ( ( ( pop ( competition ) − 125) / 400) ∗ pop( jour ) ) ^ ( | pop(competition) − pop(competition) | /50)

the goal then is to minimize the sum of both costs    familycost and competition cost

Answer (score 0):

As various comments point out, an easy approach is to greedily assign first choices at 0 cost.  The max participant constraint can be enforced during the same process.  Then repeat the process for 2nd choices, and so forth.  This step should result in an optimum cost.

Less attractive events can result in fewer than the minimum number of participants.  A second step can reassign families to these events, trying to minimize the cost.  This step might not deliver the optimum assignment if the events are managed one at a time, thereby missing the possibility of different re-arrangements.

Each step goes through the whole set of families and sorts a subset, so the final complexity is about the same as the sort function, *O*(*n* log *n*).  The tentative code below explains the gory details.  You will excuse my defining functions before referencing them; it spares me forward declarations.  You may want to jump to the `main()` function at the bottom and get back to functions as needed.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct family
{
    char members;   // members == 0 for dummy sentinel
    char choice[5]; // 0-based (unlike CSV)
    char event;     // assigned event
    char cho;        // choice index of assigned event
    int cost;       // assignment cost
    int cost2;      // re-assignment cost (2nd step)
} family;

static const unsigned int event_max = 250;
static const unsigned int event_min = 125;
static const unsigned int family_max = event_max * 5 * 7;
static const int cost_fact1[] = {0, 50, 50, 100, 100};
static const int cost_fact2[] = {0, 0, 9, 9, 9};

family *read_csv(void)
/*
* Read stdin, validating requirements.
* Event choices are decreased by 1 for 0-based computing.
*/
{
    family *fam = malloc(sizeof fam[0] * family_max + 1);
    if (fam)
    {
        unsigned count = 0;
        char buf[1024], *s;
        union jack
        {
            family f;
            char el[sizeof(family)];
        } jk;

        int tmem = 0, discard = 0;

        memset(&jk, 0, sizeof jk);
        jk.f.event = -1; // unassigned

        while ((s = fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) != NULL &&
            count < family_max)
        {
            int i;
            char *t;
            for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
            {
                long l = strtol(s, &t, 10);
                if (l <= 0 || l > 10 || strchr(",\n\0", *t) == NULL)
                    break;
                jk.el[i] = l;
                s = t + 1;
            }

            if (i == 6 && (*t == 0 || *t == '\n')) // valid, check choices
            {
                unsigned choice = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
                {
                    unsigned mask = 1 << --jk.f.choice[i];
                    if ((choice & mask) != 0)
                        break; // already seen

                    choice |= mask;
                }
                if (i == 5 && (choice & ~0x7f) == 0) // accept
                {
                    fam[count++] = jk.f;
                    tmem += jk.f.members;
                }
                else
                    ++discard;  // invalid choices
            }
            else
                ++discard; // invalid line
        }

        if (discard)
            printf("%d line(s) discarded\n", discard);
        printf("Total    %4d   %d families\n", tmem, count);

        // add sentinel and commit
        jk.el[0] = 0;
        fam[count++] = jk.f;
        return realloc(fam, sizeof fam[0] * count);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int sort_ce_cmp(void const *va, void const *vb)
/*
* Comparison function to sort pointers to family by descending members.
*/
{
    assert(va);
    assert(vb);
    family *a = *(family**)va;
    family *b = *(family**)vb;
    return b->members - a->members;
}

family **sort_ce(family *fam, int choice, int ev)
/*
* Select families having this event at this choice level
* and sort them by descending members.
*/
{
    family **fa = malloc(sizeof fa[0] * family_max + 1);
    unsigned count = 0;
    if (fa)
    {
        while (fam->members)
        {
            if (fam->event < 0 && // unassigned
                fam->choice[choice] == ev) // willing
                    fa[count++] = fam;
            ++fam;
        }

        fa[count] = NULL;
        fa = realloc(fa, sizeof fa[0] * (count + 1));
        qsort(fa, count, sizeof fa[0], sort_ce_cmp);
    }
    return fa;
}

int sort_em_cmp(void const *va, void const *vb)
/*
* Comparison function to sort pointers to family by ascending cost2.
*/
{
    assert(va);
    assert(vb);
    family *a = *(family**)va;
    family *b = *(family**)vb;
    return a->cost2 - b->cost2;
}

family **sort_em(family *fam, int ev, unsigned notany)
/*
* Select unassigned families or families not assigned to any event
* having less than the minimum number of people, and sort them by
* cost.
*/
{
    family **fa = malloc(sizeof fa[0] * family_max + 1);
    unsigned count = 0;
    if (fa)
    {
        while (fam->members)
        {
            if (fam->event < 0 || ((1 << fam->event) & notany) != 0)
            {
                int cho;
                for (cho = 0; cho < 5; ++cho)
                    if (fam->choice[cho] == ev)
                        break;
                if (cho < 5) // willing
                {
                    // cost of assigning this family to this event
                    int cf1 = cost_fact1[cho];
                    int cf2 = cost_fact2[cho];
                    int cost = cf1 + cf2 * fam->members;

                    // if this cost were less than that of step1 assignment,
                    // then why didn't step1 do this in the first place?
                    assert(cost >= fam->cost);

                    fam->cost2 = cost - fam->cost;
                    fa[count++] = fam;
                }
            }
            ++fam;
        }

        fa[count] = NULL;
        fa = realloc(fa, sizeof fa[0] * (count + 1));
        qsort(fa, count, sizeof fa[0], sort_em_cmp);
    }
    return fa;
}

void print_out(char *step, family *fam, int cost, unsigned int *event)
{
    int tfam = 0, tmem = 0, ufam = 0, umem = 0;
    while (fam->members)
    {
        ++tfam;
        tmem += fam->members;
        if (fam->event < 0)
        {
            ++ufam;
            umem += fam->members;
        }
        ++fam;
    }

    printf("Assignment after %s step, cost = %d:\n", step, cost);
    unsigned tot = 0;
    for (int ev = 0; ev < 7; ++ev)
    {
        char *ast = event[ev] < event_min || event[ev] > event_max? "*": " ";
        printf(" %s Event %d: %4d\n", ast, ev + 1, event[ev]);
        tot += event[ev];
    }
    printf("            %4d\n", tot);
    printf("Total       %4d   %d families\n", tmem, tfam);
    if (ufam)
        printf("Unassigned  %4d   %d families\n", umem, ufam);
}

int main(void)
{
    family *fam = read_csv(); // assume stdin is a CSV file

    unsigned event[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        event[i] = 0;

    int cost = 0;

    /*
    * Step 1: assign each family to their next available choice
    * constrained by max event capacity.
    */

    for (int choice = 0; choice < 5; ++choice)
    for (int ev = 0; ev < 7; ++ev)
    {
        int cf1 = cost_fact1[choice];
        int cf2 = cost_fact2[choice];

        // select families having this ev at this choice, by desc members
        family **fa = sort_ce(fam, choice, ev), **fa_alloc = fa;
        while (fa && *fa && event[ev] < event_max)
        {
            if (event[ev] + (*fa)->members <= event_max)
            {
                event[ev] += (*fa)->members;
                int this_cost = cf1 + (*fa)->members * cf2;
                cost += this_cost;
                (*fa)->cost = this_cost;
                (*fa)->event = ev;
                (*fa)->cho = choice;
            }
            ++fa;
        }

        free(fa_alloc);
    }

    print_out("first", fam, cost, event);

    unsigned any= 0;
    for (int ev = 0; ev < 7; ++ev)
        if (event[ev] < event_min)
            any |= 1 << ev;

    if (any)
    /*
    * Step 2: assign unassigned families or families from over-assigned
    * events to their next choice.
    */
    {
        for (int ev = 0; ev < 7; ++ev)
        {
            if (event[ev] >= event_min)
                continue;

            // select suitable families, sorted by cost
            family **fa = sort_em(fam, ev, ~any), **fa_alloc = fa;
            while (fa && *fa && event[ev] < event_min)
            {
                /*
                * Maybe there was a smaller/ bigger family better suited
                * for this change?
                */
                int fam_ev = (*fa)->event;
                assert(fam_ev != ev);
                if ( fam_ev < 0 ||
                    event[fam_ev] - (*fa)->members >= event_min)
                {
                    event[fam_ev] -= (*fa)->members;
                    event[ev] += (*fa)->members;
                    cost += (*fa)->cost2;
                }
                ++fa;
            }
            free(fa_alloc);
        }

        print_out("second", fam, cost, event);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the minimum number of participants cannot be met if not enough people chooses a given event.  On the other hand, some families can be left unassigned if there are too many.  In order to run tests, it is handy to have a CSV generator:

```c
/*
* Generate a CSV fot event_assign
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int count, skew = 0;
    if (argc > 1)
        count = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (count <= 0)
        count = 2;

    if (argc > 2)
        skew = atoi(argv[2]);

    char seq[7] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    srandom(time(NULL));
    while (count --> 0)
    {
        if (skew > 0 && random() % skew == 0)
            puts("3,1,2,3,4,5");
        else
        {
            for (int i = 7; i > 1; --i)
            {
                int j = random() % i;
                assert(0 <= j && j <= i);
                int tmp = seq[i];
                seq[i] = seq[j];
                seq[j] = tmp;
            }
            int members = (random() & 7) + 1;
            printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", members,
                seq[0], seq[1], seq[2], seq[3], seq[4]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```